# Is it a good idea to store website images on good drive and link to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I'm developing a website that uses a lot of images and was thinking of storing those images on Google Drive using the Drive API whenever an image is uploaded. Do you think this is a good idea and will it affect the performance in any way?

PS. After uploading to Drive from the backend, I will store a link to the image in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, maybe you should take a look at [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/).

The free plan is very generous, and the api is very easy to understand, despite the possibility to transform the images (crop, etc...).